# increase the java heap size permanently?

Tags: java, size, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

Is there a way that I can set the default heap size for the jvm on my own computer?  I want to set it to 1g, because I'm always running custom programs that always hit the overage point in the default jvm size.

I just dont want to have to remember to type -XmX1g everytime I run my java app from the command line...

There has to be an admin way to do this right?

Comment: Note, the latest Java 6 releases from Sun have increased standard heap limits.

Answer (score 66):

Apparently, `_JAVA_OPTIONS` works on Linux, too:

```
$ export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"
$ java -jar jconsole.jar &
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1g
```

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the ">" with "$" as the linux terminal prompt ends with $. At first I got confused by your answer as it resembles similar structure to a sub cli within the terminal. (eg. mysql)... which evidently has a prompt of '>'. Thanks for your answer (which, in my opinion should be the approved answer)... fingers crossed that my long running script doesn't fail after 3 hours now, changed my java heap size from 500mb to 2gb! Also, I was unsure if the 3rd line 'Picked...' was a part of the 2nd line.. so I tried both. (if that's just an output... would suggest prefix of 'Output: '. :)

Comment: Thanks @josh.thomson, I've updated the answer with your suggestion

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"
```

It's important that you have no spaces because for me it did not work. I would suggest just copying and pasting. Then I ran:

```
java -XshowSettings:vm
```

and it will tell you:

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1g

Comment: It worked for me but after some time it is going down to same heap size as it was before on my ec2 tomcat

Answer (score 24):

For Windows users, you can add a system environment variable named _JAVA_OPTIONS, and set the heap size values there. The JVM should be able to grab the virtual machine options from _JAVA_OPTIONS.

Comment: The windows solution can be reached [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17369724/1635051).

Answer (score 4):

what platform are you running?..
if its unix, maybe adding

```
alias java='java -Xmx1g'
```

to .bashrc (or similar) work

edit: Changing XmX to Xmx

Answer (score 2):

if the platform is Linux, then adding an entry in bash_profile will help.

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

then add

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx4g"
```