# Arraylist issue - Out of memory error

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am adding a parsed value to an ArrayList. I am getting a lot of parsed values in webservice. Because of this, I am getting an out of memory error. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Out of memory usually means that you're creating a whole lot of objects in a for loop or something. paste the code you've tried.

Comment: Can **you** give an example? I.e. an example out of memory stacktrace, an example piece of code causing out of memory errors, etc...

Comment: I agree with asgs.Please paste your code if some one can help you.

Comment: This is not possible to diagnose without seeing some code.

Answer (score 2):

[increase heap memory by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880855/increase-the-java-heap-size-permanently)

`-Xms64m -Xmx256m`

Answer (score 1):

You are holding to many values in memory, find a way to store some of the data outside of memory so you can keep processing values without having to raise the amount of memory you use.