# how to set default maximum heap size for Java (xmx), for linux (centos)

Tags: java, size, heap-memory

I have many small java programs running in crons in my server. I have an openvz VPS, and java is very poblematic with memory and openvz.

The best solution i have  come up so far is running my programs with:

```
java -Xmx16m class
```

This works ok, but I have many programs running, and i want to set the default maximum heap for all the system, so that i don't change all the start up scripts, and not have to remember to do that every time i write a new one.

I tried finding a way to set/change a global default value for my CentOS system, but i had no luck with that!

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880855/increase-the-java-heap-size-permanently

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try adding this to your shell profile `export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx16m`

This may or may not work depending on what JVM you are running.

Comment: I put this in bashrc file and it worked ! Thanks! I found somewhere `export JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx16m` (without _) I tried it and didn't work, now I see it was written wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Create an environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and set the new value there. That should work