# Hibernate - OutOfMemoryError - java heap size

Tags: java, hibernate, out-of-memory, size, heap-memory

I'm currently having this problem where I am executing a query that will load large of records. At first execution, it is successful, but when I
execute again, I am having java heap size out of memory.

I Know I can increase java heap size using command line, but that requires a compiled jar file.
But I am currently on the development process, so how can I increase java heap size in that case?

Im using Elipse as my IDE.

Thanks for any response.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880855/increase-the-java-heap-size-permanently. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Be careful. It may be that you're not using Hibernate properly and it certainly sounds like the application you're building could end up with memory issues.

Comment: @ james DW, although it worked by adding a vm argument -Xmx1024m, I am still considering your suggestion, I think there is also problem on how I used hibernate that's why I'm having this error!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't require a compiled jar file. Choose *Run - Run configurations... - Select your run configuration - Arguments tab*. Then enter the appropriate command line argument in the *VM arguments* text box: `-Xmx1024m` for example.

Comment: Recto, if this was the correct answer you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the **eclipse.ini** file located inside of our eclipse directory .
There you will find **Xms40m Xmx256m** parameter with some value , you can increase it to **Xms256m Xmx1024m** . Then check whether outofmemory error is still there . If its there then try tuning these parameter slightly increasing and check.

Comment: This will modify Eclipse's own memory parameters. It won't change the memory parameters of the programs launched by Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah right . Actually all the component using java memory can be handeled by providing these parameters in different places. Like when when starting the server with these parameters

Answer (score 0):

Apperently that was not enough for an answer... well, let me just copy the text from those answers instead :S

You can use the environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS to set the default heap size. This will change the heap size for all Java programs. Like this:

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"`