# Globally setting properties for JVM

Tags: java, process, operating-system

Is there any way to set certain properties that will be applicable for all java processes(`java.exe`,`javaw.exe` for windows) running on that machine ?

More clearly suppose I want to use a specific timezone to be applied for all java processes running in that machine(without changing the system timezone).

I know we can pass it as `-D` argument, but it will be applicable only for that java process right.But I need it in the other way- for every java process started.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you have only one JRE installation on those machines? Means, all `java`/`javaw` processes you are launching are launched from the same JRE/JDK installation?

Comment: yes. assume in that way

Comment: can't u just call a method on each main method you have: e.g. loadProperty();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tried with Java 8:

You can use the environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to specify default parameters for `java.exe` and `javaw.exe`, for example

```
C:> set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Quick and dirty test for `javaw`:

```
package com.example;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class PropertyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = (String) System.getProperties().get("file.encoding");

        JTextPane txt = new JTextPane();
        txt.setText(value);
        JFrame main = new JFrame();
        main.add(txt);
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
C:> javaw com.example.PropertyTest
```

[image]

```
C:> set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
C:> javaw com.example.PropertyTest
```

[image]

By setting the environment variable as a system environment variable, it applies to all java processes.

See also

- http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-set-java-properties-system-wide.html which specifies some additional environment variables (which I have not tested).
- [Java System Environment Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677346/java-system-environment-variable) on StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks @Andreas Fester.Do you have any list of such java_options available in java(not custom)

Comment: You should be able to pass all command line parameters through `_JAVA_OPTIONS` which are supported by java/javaw (probably passing the main class is not supported). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html for the MS Windows specific command line reference.

Comment: thanks @Andreas Fester

Comment: This answer is the savior of mankind!