# Unrecognized option: --add-opens when passed with _JAVA_OPTIONS

Tags: java, java-opts, javaoptions

I am trying to fix [the issue](https://community.sonatype.com/t/exception-running-cli-tool-in-java-17/8937) with running Nexus IQ scanner using Java 17 runtime.

The error is

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7225790e

So I try to pass `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` fix to the JVM which runs `nexus-iq-cli.jar`.

Unfortunately, I do not have a full control over `java -jar ...` command which gets executed on CI, otherwise I would just pass `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` explicitly. Because of that limitation I try to use some other ways to set global JVM argument settings. One way to do it which came to my mind is using [`_JAVA_OPTIONS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677804/3581539) environment variable.

The thing which surprises me is that Java quits with an error:

> Unrecognized option: --add-opens

When I try to pass it as follows:

```bash
# with unix shell you can set value to some variable and execute something in one line
_JAVA_OPTIONS='--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED' java
```

On the other hand, Java is totally fine and acts as expected when I pass this option directly as:

```bash
java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

What am I missing and what are the other possible ways to pass `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` argument if I do not have a direct control over the `java -jar` command which CI executes to perform Nexus IQ scan step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turned out that since Java 9 the modern proper way to achieve what I want is [using the `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#using-the-jdk_java_options-launcher-environment-variable) environment variable.

`_JAVA_OPTIONS` [was an undocumented feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736904/3581539)

Here is an excerpt from [JDK 9 release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-enhancements.html):

> JDK 9 supports a new environment variable `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` to prepend options to those specified on the command line. The new environment variable has several advantages over the legacy/unsupported `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable including the ability to include `java` launcher options and `@file` support

My final solution to Nexus IQ issue was to add the following 2 options for JVM:

```bash
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

If you will face `InaccessibleObjectException`  on some other package, just add one more `--add-opens`

Comment: It has an issue with some operating system: see https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/546 and https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/303 where it is suggested to use `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` as a temporary workaround.