# OS X command line java windows appearing

Tags: java, macos, command-line

All of a sudden, after years of using OS X Java without any problems, now, when starting ActiveMQ from the commandline a 'bin' application window appears. 'About bin' -> 1.0. When starting tomcat from the commandline an org.apache.catalina.startup.bootstrap window appears. Frustrating as they steal focus from the terminal. Never happened before. Just wondering if anyone knew why they might be suddenly appearing. I've seen lots of references to headless but this is the OS doing this for no apparent reason, rather than the java apps.

Answer (score 2):

Well who knows what happened to Java but this answer provides the solution:

[How to set java system properties globally on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627405/how-to-set-java-system-properties-globally-on-os-x)

i.e.

~/.profile

export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.awt.headless=true