# How to fix "OutOfMemoryError: java heap space" while compiling MonoDroid App in MonoDevelop

Tags: android, build, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

When I try to **compile** (not execute) one of my projects, I recently get the following error:

```
Tool /usr/bin/java execution started with arguments: -jar /Applications/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar --no-strict --dex --output=obj/Debug/android/bin/classes.dex obj/Debug/android/bin/classes /Developer/MonoAndroid/usr/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-8/mono.android.jar FlurryAnalytics/Jars/FlurryAgent.jar Jars/android-support-v4.jar 

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpecSet.<init>(RegisterSpecSet.java:49)
        at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpecSet.mutableCopy(RegisterSpecSet.java:383)
        at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableInfo.mutableCopyOfStarts(LocalVariableInfo.java:169)
        at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableExtractor.processBlock(LocalVariableExtractor.java:104)
        at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableExtractor.doit(LocalVariableExtractor.java:90)
        at com.android.dx.ssa.LocalVariableExtractor.extract(LocalVariableExtractor.java:56)
        at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:50)
        at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:99)
        at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:73)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:273)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:134)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:87)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:487)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

Other projects build as expected. I think I need to increase the heap size for this java build step? But how?

Comment: you used many large size images in your app ?

Comment: No large images in the App. Mind that it's a compile time error and has nothing to do with executing the App on the device.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an option in Xamarin Studio to increase the Java Heap Size.

Project Options -> Android Build -> Advanced -> Java Heap Size.

[image]

Comment: I use this UI setting for quite a while now. Much better than exporting the _JAVA_OPTIONS!

Comment: What value to put here?

Comment: Ok, `1G` was enough for me.

Comment: In Visual Studio, this is on Project Properties / Android Options / Advanced tab.

Comment: Be mindful of the selected configuration. In the picture above, Debug configuration is selected, make sure to also change the value for Release so that your release build also uses the increased value.

Answer (score 5):

[This suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880855/increase-the-java-heap-size-permanently) did the trick:

```
$ export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"
$ /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/MonoDevelop
```

I have a few jar files in my project. Flurry, Maps and Newtonsoft... aparently this is enough to bomb the build.

Thanks to the awesome Xamarin Support team for their quick response and pointing out the solution! They are working on reducing the needed memory footprint for external jars.