# Xamarin (monodroid) + adMob build error

Tags: android, xamarin.android, admob, xamarin

I have a problem.
I have an application builded with monodroid libraries.
Version of android sdk 4.0.3 (API level 15), GoogleAdMobAdsSdk v.6.4.1.
I made separated project to import adsdk to xamarin, add to Metadata.xml attributes. This project compiling without errors. But when i have a reference to this project from my monodroid application i get an error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Tool exited with code: 3. Output: 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.android.dx.util.IntList.growIfNeeded(IntList.java:274)
    at com.android.dx.util.IntList.add(IntList.java:217)
    at com.android.dx.util.LabeledList.addLabelIndex(LabeledList.java:96)
    at com.android.dx.util.LabeledList.set(LabeledList.java:184)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.BasicBlockList.set(BasicBlockList.java:77)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convertBasicBlocks(SsaToRop.java:260)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convert(SsaToRop.java:124)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convertToRopMethod(SsaToRop.java:70)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:102)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:73)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:273)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:134)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:87)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:487)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
 (MyMegaMonoDroidApplication)
```

Where is my error?
ThnX.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523257/how-to-fix-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-while-compiling-monodroid-app-in

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the Java Heap Size = 1G (or 512M might help you).

Here is how to do that for Xamarin Studio https://stackoverflow.com/a/24833518/883738

In Visual Studio you should do that in the [Android project properties](https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/xamarin/images/java_max_heap_size_property_xamarin_vs.png)