# Implementing MultiDex results in compiling for so long, and finally heap space error

Tags: android, android-multidex

I have a big Android project where I got the **Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536** error; I believe some of you guys have definitely gone through this issue before. This is an error due to too many methods referenced in the app.

I have looked for different sources online and found [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) might be the best solution.

And I did the following:

1. Added `multiDexEnabled = true` in the `defaultConfig` block of **build.gradle**.
2. Added the following dependency:

   ```
   dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
   }
   ```
3. Overrided the following code inside my App class.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
   }
   ```

Now, the error is gone, but I have a new problem. When I run the app, the compiler takes more than 3 minutes for compiling and running the app, finally giving me this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I understand this error occurs due to heavy memory usage, but I don't know how to solve it. I am using Android Studio 1.0.2, and Android API 21.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I already checked [How to fix “OutOfMemoryError: java heap space” while compiling MonoDroid App in MonoDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523257/how-to-fix-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-while-compiling-monodroid-app-in), but this does not cover the reason of the problem, and moreover, I am not using Xamarin Studio.

**EDIT2**:

The exact symptom is like this:
When I compile the code, the gradle console shows me hundreds of warnings saying "Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class" (which some other stackoverflow answers suggest that are not serious warnings), and then shows nothing but a blinking cursor for a while, and after about one minute, it gives me the error.

Comment: There you go.. Your question is reopened..

Comment: Thanks.. Any idea about the question?

Comment: probably follow this to increase heap size, http://stackoverflow.com/q/18723755/603744 and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it already, and setting the Xmx1024m didn't work.

Comment: u shud try higher value than 1024.. like 2048 or even more..

Comment: Yes, I am trying that. By the way, what might be the reason of the long compiling do you think? The gradle console shows me hundreds of warnings "Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class", and then stops for a while, and after about one minute, it gives me the error

Comment: I am not aware of that.. fortunately mine was not  the big project, so removing few unwanted libs solved my issue. I really didn't solve the 65K problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried adding the heap size adjustment to your `build.gradle` file? For example this will set the max heap size for dexing to 4GB.

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: In the Android module build.gradle, not the project build.gradle.  It is semi-documented here:  

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-dex-options

Comment: This looks like a solution. I have a question. Does this long compiling have anything to do with the working performance of the apk?

Comment: I stumbled onto it while Google-ing the error last week.  Not clear what the "4g" actually means but it made the error go away.  :)

Comment: It means 4GB I guess?

Comment: Oh, duh, that makes sense.

Comment: Performance, don't know.  I ended up pulling out the library that pushed me into trying the MultiDex stuff. I'll revisit it eventually.

Comment: any negative side effects of increasing max heap size?

Answer (score -1):

Try this in build gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
           targetSdkVersion 21
// Enabling multidex support.
           multiDexEnabled true
    }
 }
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  }
```

Comment: What does this do?