# Set default heap size in Windows

Tags: java, windows, heap-memory

I want to set Java heap size permanently and don't want to run every jar file with options.
I use Windows and Java 1.7.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Setup **JAVA_OPTS** as a system variable with the following content:

`JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"`

After that in a command prompt run the following commands:

```
SET JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

This can be explained as follows:

- allocate at minimum 256MBs of heap
- allocate at maximum 512MBs of heap

These values should be changed according to application requirements.

EDIT:

You can also try adding it through the Environment Properties menu which can be found at:

1. From the **Desktop**, right-click **My Computer** and click **Properties**.
2. Click **Advanced System Settings** link in the left column.
3. In the **System Properties** window click the **Environment Variables** button.
4. Click New to add a new variable name and value.
5. For variable name enter **JAVA_OPTS** for variable value enter **-Xms256m -Xmx512m**
6. Click ok and close the **System Properties** Tab.
7. Restart any java applications.

EDIT 2:

**JAVA_OPTS** is a system variable that stores various settings/configurations for your local **Java Virtual Machine**. By having **JAVA_OPTS** set as a system variable all applications running on top of the **JVM** will take their settings from this parameter.

To setup a system variable you have to complete the steps listed above from 1 to 4.

Comment: This does not work, and results in an invalid heapsize definition error.

Comment: @Scorb this worked in 2013 for sure, feel free to suggest edits to what works for current Windows versions and I'll gladly accept them

Answer (score 19):

Try setting a Windows System Environment variable called `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with the heap size you want.  Java should be able to find it and act accordingly.

Comment: How to format that variable value please ?..