# Unable to start the JVM - Windows 7

Tags: jvm

Our company IT recently went through an upgrade and I don't know what else they changed to the defaults but Excel 2013 32-bit (w/ MATLAB Compiler Runtime add in) crashes multiple times a day and it's driving me crazy.

I looked through the solutions to other similar questions but still having no luck. The exact error that I'm receiving is attached in the picture below. I've tried editing the environment variable to various amounts and checked that the free physical memory is available (has 16G total and usually half is free)

Running `java -version` in the command prompt returns:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b31)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

The Java Control Panel Runtime Environment Settings reference **javaw.exe** but I changed the environment variables on both the java.exe and javaw.exe (in both Program Files and Program Files (x86).

> Unable to start the JVM. 
>   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m -Xms512m
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM 
>   Could not reserve enough space for budget heap
>   There is not enough memory to start up the Java virtual machine.
>   Try quitting other applications or increasing your virtual memory

[image: JVM Error]

Comment: Thanks for attaching the image. Please add **text** of the message along with the image. This helps the search-engines and hence will help other people who have the same problem.

Comment: It may be a too obvious question but have you tried reinstalling the JRE, it sometimes solves problems like these

Comment: The error message is: 

Unable to start the JVM. 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m -Xms512m
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for budget heap

There is not enough memory to start up the Java virtual machine.
Try quitting other applications or increasing your virtual memory.

Comment: @lolatu2 Are you still seeing the same message with the same numbers? Have you tried quitting other programs to free up system memory?

Comment: I tried a bunch of different sizes and none of them seemed to work. When I took the screenshot, the size was set to 256m initial and 512m max. The written out portion shows another option I tried that was 512m initial and 1024m max

Comment: The Task Manager shows that I have 9G free out of 16G total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says it does not have enough space. 
Change the setting for JVM Maximum Memory to 1024M
`-Xmx1024m`
Are there such setting for your plugin ? You might want to Google "JVM heap size settings for Excel MAtlab plugin".

Please take a look at this question as well. [(Increase default heap size for windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369522/set-default-heap-size-in-windows)
Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried various memory limits and they didn't seem to work. I did try setting the max limit to 1024m and got the same error. How do I change the environment variables back to the default in command prompt?

Comment: I finally got it to work by changing the variable name to JAVA_OPTS instead of the _JAVA_OPTIONS that I was using earlier.